# DAG for Difference in Difference Studies

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

I have been looking for DAGs to represent diff-in-diff research designs but did not come across any. How do you represent state/time fixed effects and time-varying effects on a DAG?

Comment: DAG = Directed acyclic graph?